# Adding Y values of duplicate X values together in XYSeries

Tags: java, 2d, jfreechart

```
public XYSeriesCollection CreateDataset(int startColumn, int endColumn, int startRow, int endRow) {


    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");

    for (int j = startRow; j < endRow; j++) {
            String curVal = m_Data[j][endColumn];
            if (isInt(curVal)) {
                XYDataItem item = series.addOrUpdate(Integer.parseInt(m_Data[j][startColumn]), Integer.parseInt(curVal));
                if (item != null) {
                    int temp = item.getY().intValue() + Integer.parseInt(curVal);
                    int temp1 = series.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(m_Data[j][startColumn]));
                    /*Integer temp2 = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(m_Data[j][startColumn]));
                    series.update((Number) temp2, temp);*/
                    series.updateByIndex(temp1, temp);
                }
            } /*else if (isDouble(curVal)) {
                series.add(Integer.parseInt(m_Data[j][startColumn]), Double.parseDouble(curVal));
            } else {
                series.add(Integer.parseInt(m_Data[j][startColumn]), 0);
            }*/


    }
        dataset.addSeries(series);

    return dataset;

}
```

Contained in m_Data is a CSV file that has been formatted into String[Rows][Columns]. What I am trying to do is make a dataset used for a XYBarchart where the startColumn indicates which column, and the for loop is used to go through the rows of that column to take the values for the X-Axis (keys?). The values for Y are retrieved from the endColumn on the same row.

In the m_Data array however are duplicate values, so when using a column with duplicate values as the X-Axis, I need to add the corresponding Y values together. However the method I have implemented does not seem to work, and instead just adds the first encountered value to the series.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subclass `XYSeries` and replace either `XYDataItem addOrUpdate(Number x, Number y)` or `public void add(XYDataItem item, boolean notify)` so that rather the additional values are added rather then overwriting the existing Y value.

Alternatively iterate through you dataset twice once to aggregate duplicates and then to add it to an  `XYSeries`